# How to get dynamic Jenkins-parameter(Parameterized Build) from any backend script(Groovy/Shell)

Tags: jenkins

I have a groovy script which can provide multiple choices for one of the parameters in my Jenkins-Parameterised-Build.

Please let me know how I can integrate this groovy script with Jenkins job

Comment: Can you share what you have tried already and the groovy script

Comment: import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
data = "groovy /opt/main.groovy".execute().text
def ids = "${data}"
def idList = new JsonSlurper().parseText(ids)
return idList

Comment: I'm using the above code in Jenkins-ActiveChoiceParameter field.